# Huisken's Distance Comparison principle for Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

So I have been studying curvature shortening flows, and I was curious if there were some variants of Huisken's distance comparison  principle for Mean curvature flows or even the Ricci flow. It seems that there could be some analogous constructions for these flows, but I am not aware of any. I would appreciate it if someone could give me some suggestions of papers to look at. Thanks.